# Error during shared preferences in JSON parsing android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, sharedpreferences

I am developing a library management system. My application has a login activity. The activity is connected to the MYSQL database which when after logging in successfully opens OpenProfile.java . This contains various tags for book details like username, details, book1 etc which areretreived from a MYSQL databse too. I want the OpenProfile activity to automatically take the value of username as shared preference from login activity and post the book details for that specific user. I am unable to execute this.

**OpenProfile.java**

```
package com.example.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class OpenProfile extends ListActivity {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;



    // testing on Emulator:
    private static final String READ_PROFILE_URL = "http://crshaggy.byethost7.com/webservice/profile.php";



    // JSON IDS:
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OpenProfile.this);
    private final String TAG_USERNAME = sp.getString("username", "anon");
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_BOOK1 = "book1";
    private static final String TAG_BOOK2 = "book2";
    private static final String TAG_BOOK3 = "book3";
    private static final String TAG_DETAILS = "DETAILS";
    private static final String TAG_FINE = "fine";
    private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
    private static final String TAG_RETURN_DATE = "return_date";


    // An array of all of our comments
    private JSONArray mComments = null;
    // manages all of our comments in a list.
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // note that use read_comments.xml instead of our single_post.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.open_profile);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        // loading the comments via AsyncTask
        new LoadComments().execute();
    }


    /**
     * Retrieves recent post data from the server.
     */
    public void updateJSONdata() {



        mCommentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(READ_PROFILE_URL);


        try {


            mComments = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);

            // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
            for (int i = 0; i < mComments.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = mComments.getJSONObject(i);

                // gets the content of each tag
                String username = c.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                String details = c.getString(TAG_DETAILS);
                String book1 = c.getString(TAG_BOOK1);
                String book2 = c.getString(TAG_BOOK2);
                String book3 = c.getString(TAG_BOOK3);
                String fine = c.getString(TAG_FINE);
                String return_date = c.getString(TAG_RETURN_DATE);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                map.put(TAG_DETAILS, details);
                map.put(TAG_BOOK1, book1);
                map.put(TAG_BOOK2, book2);
                map.put(TAG_BOOK3, book3);
                map.put(TAG_FINE, fine);
                map.put(TAG_RETURN_DATE, return_date);


                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mCommentList.add(map);

                // annndddd, our JSON data is up to date same with our array
                // list
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Inserts the parsed data into the listview.
     */
    private void updateList() {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mCommentList,
                R.layout.open_profile, new String[] { TAG_USERNAME, TAG_DETAILS,
                        TAG_BOOK1, TAG_BOOK2, TAG_BOOK3, TAG_FINE, TAG_RETURN_DATE }, new int[] { R.id.username, R.id.details,
                        R.id.book1, R.id.book2, R.id.book3, R.id.fine, R.id.return_date, });


        setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();    
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


            }
        });
    }

    public class LoadComments extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(OpenProfile.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading Comments...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            updateJSONdata();
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            updateList();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the PHP file for book details 
**profile.php**

```
<?php


require("config.inc.php");
$username=$_GET['username'];
//initial query

$query = "Select username, details, book1, book2, book3, fine, return_date from user_details WHERE username='$username'";

//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
   // $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    $ex->getMessage();
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
   // die(json_encode($response));
}


$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();

        $post["username"]    = $row["username"]; 
        $post["details"]    = $row["details"];
$post["book1"]    = $row["book1"];
$post["book2"]    = $row["book2"];
$post["book3"]    = $row["book3"];
$post["fine"]    = $row["fine"];
$post["return_date"]    = $row["return_date"];


        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);


} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```

**Error Log**

```
    08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121): Process: com.example.test, PID: 1121
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.OpenProfile}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2121)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:374)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:369)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at com.example.test.OpenProfile.<init>(OpenProfile.java:45)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
08-07 09:14:06.018: E/AndroidRuntime(1121):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
```

Comment: This has to go inside onCreate() SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OpenProfile.this);

Comment: It's object will become local then

Comment: No, I'm sorry for not being clear. You can keep it declared there, just don't put the stuff after the equal sign until you're inside a method.

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception at 'sp.getString("username","anon");'

Answer (score 0):

Before `onCreate()`, `onResume()` is called, the O.S. won't know "`OpenProfile.this`"
So, declaring would be with rest of the variables and initialization inside `onCreate()`..like:

```
...
        SharedPreferences sp;
private final String TAG_USERNAME;
     // manages all of our comments in a list.
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mCommentList;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // note that use read_comments.xml instead of our single_post.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.open_profile);  
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OpenProfile.this);
TAG_USERNAME = sp.getString("username", "anon");
...
```

Comment: Done this. Still getting a null pointer exception at sp.getString("username","anon")

Comment: i am sorry i didn't see that, hope u shifted that line in onCreate()

Answer (score 0):

Initialize both `sp` and `TAG_USERNAME` in `onCreate` and don't make `TAG_USERNAME` a `final` property:

```
SharedPreferences sp;
private String TAG_USERNAME;
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String READ_PROFILE_URL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // note that use read_comments.xml instead of our single_post.xml
   setContentView(R.layout.open_profile);
   sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OpenProfile.this);
   TAG_USERNAME = sp.getString("username", "anon");
   Log.d("mylog", "TAG_USERNAME = " + TAG_USERNAME );
   READ_PROFILE_URL = String.format("http://crshaggy.byethost7.com/webservice/profile.php?username=%s", TAG_USERNAME);
   Log.d("mylog", "READ_PROFILE_URL = " + READ_PROFILE_URL );
   // loading the comments via AsyncTask
   new LoadComments().execute();
}
```

Comment: How to post the username which is our shared preference to the php file so that it returns the desired row?

Comment: It is not showing any error now. But there is no post displayed in the activity. Just a blank activity